# Qt program with Shell

Tags: linux, qt, shell, testing

I want to write a testing program. It will open a special `*.tests` file and test direct program with tests from the file.

I need to:

1. Run some program. e.g `./main -testing 45 563 67`
2. Listen to result.

How I can to do it? I want to run program `main` with some tests and listen to its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ues the [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html) class to start your program.

```
QString program = "./main";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-testing" << "45" << "563" << ...;

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Then you can use the [`waitForFinished`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#waitForFinished) to wait for it to finish.
[`exitCode`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#exitCode) will give you the return code.

The [`readAllStandardOutput`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) (or `*Error`) methods allow you to read what the process has output to the console.

Comment: Thank you. But I have one question. readAllStandardOutput returns QByteArray. If program will write - (7\n67\n78\n), what format will be qbytearray?

Comment: It will have exactly that format. You can create a QString from a QByteArray, or create a QBuffer from it.